# Why is this C program reporting more throughput than nload?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, centos, benchmarking

I run the following C program between two machines with 10GibE; the program reports 12Gib/s whereas `nload` reports a (more believable) 9.2Gib/s.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the program?

```
.
.
#define BUFFSZ (4*1024)
char buffer[BUFFSZ];
.
.
  start = clock();

  while (1) {
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, BUFFSZ);
    if (n < 0)
       error("ERROR writing to socket");
    if (++blocks % (1024*1024) == 0)
    {
      blocks = 0;
      printf("32Gib at %6.2lf Gib/s\n", 32.0/(((double) (clock() - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
      start = clock();
    }
  }
```

This is CentOs 6.0 on Linux 2.6.32; nload 0.7.3, gcc 4.4.4.

Comment: Could it be that your program is measuring throughput *into* a system buffer and nload is measuring throughout *out* of it?

Comment: @spraff you remark is true if the socket is open in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @Fixee can you provide the socket opening code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `clock()` returns an estimate of the *CPU time* used by the program, not the wall-clock time - so your calculation indicates that you are transferring 12GiB per second of CPU time used.  Instead, use `clock_gettime()` with the clock ID `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` to measure wall-clock time.

Secondly, after `write()` returns the data hasn't necessarily been sent to the network yet - merely copied into the kernel buffers for sending.  This will give you a higher reported transfer rate at the start of the connection.

Comment: Changing to `clock_gettime()` makes the program report correct throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value from read() n might be shorter than BUFFSZ.

EDIT: oops, that should have been write().